# SwiftUI displayModeButtonItem is internally managed

Tags: swiftui, xcode12

I am getting this message in the console every time I navigate to another screen:

```
[Assert] displayModeButtonItem is internally managed and not exposed for DoubleColumn style. Returning an empty, disconnected UIBarButtonItem to fulfill the non-null contract.
```

Currently I have navigation view set up in the entry point of the app like so

```
NavigationView {
        KeyboardView(matrixVM: matrixVM, isNavigationBarHidden: $isNavigationBarHidden)
            .background(Color("background")
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
            .navigationBarTitle("Workspace")
            .navigationBarHidden(self.isNavigationBarHidden)
            .onAppear {
                self.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        }
    }
```

And then inside the KeyboardView I have the navigationlink

```
NavigationLink(destination: NotebookView(isNavigationBarHidden: $isNavigationBarHidden, saved: matrixVM), label: {
                            Text("Notebooks")
                                .font(.system(size: 14, design: .rounded))
                                .fontWeight(.medium)
                                .foregroundColor(Color("text"))
                                .padding(.trailing, 10)
                        })
```

Inside the NotebookView I have a list of navigation links (each notebook linking to its detail page)

```
ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                        ForEach(notebooks, id: \.self) { notebook in
                            
                            NavigationLink(destination: ExpandedSnippet(matrixVM: saved ,notebook: notebook)
                                            .navigationBarTitle("Notebook", displayMode: .inline)) {
                                SnippetCard(notebook: notebook, matrixVM: saved)
                                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                            }
                            .padding(.bottom, 30)
                        }
                    }
```

Everything seems to be working but just a few hours ago it didn't (I was using tabbar and it suddenly started crashing after working for weeks). I feel like it's a bit of a mess and I am doing something wrong. Any idea why? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I am getting this with Xcode 12.1 when running on the iPhone or iPhone simulator but not the iPad simulator.

Attaching this to the NavigationView fixed it for me.

```
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

Comment: If you still want to keep the double column style on iPad, you can [use a different style based on the size class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67289627/14351818)

Answer (score 9):

**Using Xcode 12.1 (12A7403), this appears to be fixed.**

The previous answer remains below for posterity.

I ran into this earlier as well using the latest Xcode 12 beta (12A8189).

This provides a simple MVP to demonstrate the problem.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("First View")
                }
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail Title")) {
                Text("New View")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                Button(action: {
                                    print("Clicked")
                                }) {
                                    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                                })
    }
}
```

The issue comes down to what device I use.

When running this on an iPhone, I will see the message that OP posts.

When running this on an iPad, I will not see any message.

Now, why is it doing this?

For starters, you can look at this [Apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller/1623196-displaymodebuttonitem) for the `displayModeButtonItem` that the assertion references.

Or, check out the screenshots of the above code in action.

iPhone:

[image]

iPad:

[image]

Notice how the iPad shows the icon for `displayModeButtonItem`, while the iPhone does not.

Based on this, my take is that Apple made a mistake. Maybe it will get fixed in the next release?

The best thing you can do would be [to file a bug](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).

FWIW, I did look at the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12-beta-release-notes) and could not find any reference to this.

Answer (score 7):

Attaching `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` to the NavigationView does indeed silence the error.

Unfortunately, this is not always a desirable solution, and can sometimes introduce another existing bug specific to `StackNavigationViewStyle()` in which: [a selected list row's background color remains gray after navigating back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64042112/selected-list-rows-background-remains-grey-selected-after-navigating-back-in).

Answer (score 7):

After updating my iOS 13 app to iOS 14, I am seeing this error and my navbar was not working properly.

To fix this error, I just have to do one change:

```
NavigationView{
// other code
}
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I received this error on a `NavigationLink` using the `navigationBarItems()` modifier. Adding `navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` to my `NavigationView` did not solve the issue. I also tried `zIndex()` and `layoutPriority()` to no avail. My issue was resolved by using the toolbar instead.

Before

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing:
    NavigationLink(
        destination: OtherView(),
        label: {
            trailingImage
        })
    )
```

After

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        NavigationLink(
            destination: OtherView(),
            label: {
                trailingImage
            })
    }
}
```